# Angular TypeScript change/replace item in Array with dialog

Tags: angular, typescript

data-Service.ts

```
export interface ContactListEntry {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  vorname: string;
  mobileNumber: number;
  secondMobileNumber: number;
  email: string;
  secondEmail: string;
  roomNumber: string;
  task: string;
  notes: string;
}


export const contact: ContactListEntry[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Mustermann',vorname:'Max', mobileNumber: 123456, secondMobileNumber: 654321, email: 'MaxMustermann@beispiel.de', secondEmail: 'MaxMustermannSecond@beispiel.de', roomNumber: 'A101', task: "Rechenzentrum", notes: 'Notiz1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'MMM',vorname:'nnn', mobileNumber: 111, secondMobileNumber: 222, email: 'mmm@beispiel.de', secondEmail: 'mmmsecond@beispiel.de', roomNumber: 'A102', task: "Rechenzentrum2", notes: 'Notiz2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'EEE',vorname:'EEE', mobileNumber: 333, secondMobileNumber: 444, email: 'nnn@beispiel.de', secondEmail: 'nnnsecond@beispiel.de', roomNumber: 'B202', task: "Rechenzentrum3", notes: 'Notiz3' },
];
```

table-list.ts ( Main )

```
export class TableListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private DataServiceService: MatDialog) {
    this.DataServiceService = DataServiceService;
  }

object = contact;

  entry: ContactListEntry = {
    id: null,
    name: '',
    vorname: '',
    mobileNumber: null, // Muss zu String umgeändert werden!
    secondMobileNumber: null, // Muss zu String umgeändert werden!
    email: '',
    secondEmail: '',
    roomNumber: '',
    task: '',
    notes: '',
  }


openDialogEdit(entryEdit: any) {
    var data = {
      entryEdit: entryEdit,
    }
    this.DataServiceService.open(DialogEditContactComponent, {minWidth: "400px", minHeight: "400px", data});

  }
```

dialog-edit-contact.ts

```
  constructor(private dataServiceService: DataServiceService,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data: any) {

    this.data = data;




    this.entryEdit = this.data
  

   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  data: any;
  
  entryEdit: ContactListEntry = {
    id: 1,
    name: '',
    vorname: '',
    mobileNumber: null,
    secondMobileNumber: null,
    email: '',
    secondEmail: '',
    roomNumber: '',
    task: '',
    notes: '  ',
  }

  saveEditContact(entryEdit: any){



    entryEdit = contact.findIndex((obj => obj.id == entryEdit.id)); 
    
    contact[entryEdit].name = entryEdit.name



}
}
```

I want that when i open my dialog component that i can edit the Array and it sends to the Array in the dataService and been saved.

The function works if i write all in the table-list.ts but i want that i can use it in the dialog-edit-contact.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can add getter and setter methods in your data service to provide easier access to this contact array. I'm not sure if the above data-service.ts code is your entire service file, but I would rewrite it as a typical service:

I also took the liberty to rename `contact` to `contacts` to be more specific that it's multiple `contacts`, not a single `contact`.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  contacts: ContactListEntry[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mustermann',vorname:'Max', mobileNumber: 123456, secondMobileNumber: 654321, email: 'MaxMustermann@beispiel.de', secondEmail: 'MaxMustermannSecond@beispiel.de', roomNumber: 'A101', task: "Rechenzentrum", notes: 'Notiz1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'MMM',vorname:'nnn', mobileNumber: 111, secondMobileNumber: 222, email: 'mmm@beispiel.de', secondEmail: 'mmmsecond@beispiel.de', roomNumber: 'A102', task: "Rechenzentrum2", notes: 'Notiz2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'EEE',vorname:'EEE', mobileNumber: 333, secondMobileNumber: 444, email: 'nnn@beispiel.de', secondEmail: 'nnnsecond@beispiel.de', roomNumber: 'B202', task: "Rechenzentrum3", notes: 'Notiz3' },
  ];

  // Get all current contacts
  getContacts() {
    return this.contacts;
  }

  // Update a contact at a given index
  setContact(contact: ContactListEntry, i: number) {
    this.contacts[i] = { ...contact };
  }
}
```

Now in your `dialog-edit-contact.ts`,

```
  saveEditContact(entryEdit: any){
    // get current contacts array
    const contacts = this.dataService.getContacts();

    // Find which index the current contact is located
    entryEdit = contacts.findIndex(obj => obj.id === entryEdit.id); 

    // Here you can now update any values using the "..." (spread operator)
    const updatedContact = {
      ...contacts[entryEdit],
      ...entryEdit
    }
    
    // Now using the new setter method, pass the updatedContact to be updated
    this.dataService.setContact(updatedContact, entryEdit);
  }
```

With the spread operator (`...`), here's what's happening->

```
    const updatedContact = {
      // First we get the current contact object,
      ...contacts[entryEdit],

      // Then we overwrite any properties with the new edited object
      ...entryEdit
    }
```

This makes sure that you can update the object no matter what properties were edited. And if new properties were added, they would then be merged into the updated ContactListEntry object.

Hopefully this answers your question, please let me know if you have questions!

Comment: Hello thank you for you answer but it doesnt work i try it but in const updatedContact and updateContact is contact red ( dialog-edit-contact.component.ts(67, 11): 'contacts' is declared here. )

Comment: I'm not sure where the error is referring to, but I did spot a bug in my answer, `contact` should have been `contacts`: `...contact[entryEdit],` was changed to `...contacts[entryEdit],`

Comment: Yes i changed it but it doesnt work